Was trägt "teilweise" bei in "teilweise bis zu"?
In diesem Video, sagt der Host:

2002 zum Beispiel lag die SPD zwei Monate vor der Bundestagswahl in
den Umfragen um teilweise bis zu neun Prozentpunkte hinter der Union
zurück.

Was trägt "teilweise" zu diesem Satz bei? Ist es nicht schon durch "bis zu" klar, dass es in bestimmten Umfragen um weniger als 9% gehen könnte?

Es trägt nichts bei, was nicht schon durch "bis zu" ausgesagt wird.

Ich denke, mit dem Verständnis der Intention hinter der zusätzlichen Einschränkung durch das Adverb "teilweise" gibt es hier keine Probleme, wenn man die Phrasen des Politikjournalismus kennt: gemeint ist, dass der Rückstand der SPD von neun Prozentpunkten zwar in einer oder mehr Umfragen gesehen wurde, es aber auch einen relevanten Anteil Umfragen gibt, die diesen Rückstand deutlich kleiner sehen.
Das so kompakt (und vage) auszudrücken, ist eben Teil des journalistischen Stils.

Eine nichtpleonastische Interpretation erscheint mir möglich. Es gibt Umfragen zu verschiedenen Zeitpunkten von verschiedenen Instituten. Mit einem Adverbial wie teilweise kann man ausdrücken, für wie viele davon der Satzinhalt wahr ist.

Die SPD lag {in den meisten Umfragen, in vielen Umfragen, in einigen Umfragen} zurück.

(Das in den Umfragen um teilweise … im Ausgangsbeispiel würde wie in einigen Umfragen interpretieren.) Mit bis zu … Prozent wird dann eine Größenordnung hinzugefügt. Es handelt sich um unabhängige Dimensionen:

Die SPD lag in einer Minderheit der Umfragen vorne, in den meisten aber fünf bis neun Prozentpunkte zurück.

Ob der Sprecher das im Sinn hatte, weiß ich nicht.

Die Wortreihenfolge "um teilweise bis zu neun Prozentpunkte" läßt diese Interpretation m.E. nicht zu. Die Einschränkung "teilweise" bezieht sich auf die Größenordnung.

Aber bei teilweise um bis zu wäre es möglich?

Genau das meine ich damit, ja. Also den ersten Absatz sehe ich genauso, nur würde ich als Satzinhalt hier die "bis zu 9 Prozent" verstehen.

Danke für die Antwort!
